# How to set MEMCACHED_SERVERS environmental variable for memcstat

Tags: memcached

I've installed memcached and libmemcached-tools on ubuntu 18.04.
Both of these commands work:

```
memcstat --servers=localhost
memcstat --servers=127.0.0.1
```

But in the man page for memcstat it says:

> You can specify servers via the option:
>
> --servers
>
> or via the environment variable:
>
> 'MEMCACHED_SERVERS, --args'

I can't find any examples of how to set the MEMCACHED_SERVERS variable. I've tried:

```
MEMCACHED_SERVERS=127.0.0.1
MEMCACHED_SERVERS="127.0.0.1"
MEMCACHED_SERVERS="--args 127.0.0.1"
MEMCACHED_SERVERS="localhost"
MEMCACHED_SERVERS=localhost
MEMCACHED_SERVERS="--servers=localhost"
```

But all I get from memcstat is "No servers provided".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to set an environment variable:

```
#> MEMCACHED_SERVERS='127.0.0.1' memcstat
```

otherwise:

```
#> export MEMCACHED_SERVERS='127.0.0.1'
#> memcstat
```

Comment: I forgot about the export statement. Thanks.